# Python control flow reverts "backwards" instead of going forward

Tags: python, class, inheritance

First and foremost, I literally could not think of a better title to this question, so please bear with me.

I'm currently writing a Python program that has 3 classes (1 Parent and 2 child classes), where a user is being asked to describe various features of either a car or pickup truck, to subsequently add the vehicle to a virtual garage (dictionary). Depending on what vehicle type is selected, some general questions will be asked as well as specific questions pertaining to the vehicle type:

```
class Vehicle:

def __init__(self):
    self.vehicle_type_request = int(input("Hello! Press 1 to add a Car to your garage or 2 to add a Pickup: "))
    self.make = input("Please enter the make of your vehicle: ")
    self.model = input("Please enter the model of your vehicle: ")
    self.color = input("Please enter the color of your vehicle: ")
    self.fuel_type = input("Please enter the fuel type: ")
    self.options = []

def welcome_message(self):
    if self.vehicle_type_request == 1:
        self.vehicle_type_request = Cars()
    else:
        self.vehicle_type_request = Pickup()
    return self.vehicle_type_request
```

However, once everything is said and done, my program gives me this. After it asks the last question "Please choose any applicable vehicle options:", it reverts back to the first question:

```
Hello! Press 1 to add a Car to your garage or 2 to add a Pickup: 1
Please enter the make of your vehicle: test
Please enter the model of your vehicle: test
Please enter the color of your vehicle: test
Please enter the fuel type: test
Please choose any applicable vehicle options: test
Hello! Press 1 to add a Car to your garage or 2 to add a Pickup: 1
Please enter the make of your vehicle: test
Please enter the model of your vehicle: test
Please enter the color of your vehicle: test
Please enter the fuel type: test
Please enter the engine size: test
How many doors does your vehicle have? 2
Hello! Press 1 to add a Car to your garage or 2 to add a Pickup: 2
Please enter the make of your vehicle: test
Please enter the model of your vehicle: test
Please enter the color of your vehicle: test
Please enter the fuel type: test
Please enter the cab style: test
Please enter the bed length: test

Process finished with exit code 0
```

In theory, the program should've continued into vehicle specific questions, depending on which option the user chose. Choose 1, you get:

```
class Cars(Vehicle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        **self.engine_size = float(input("Please enter the engine size: "))
        self.num_doors = int(input("How many doors does your vehicle have? "))**

    def get_engine_size(self):
        return self.engine_size

    def get_num_doors(self):
        return self.num_doors
```

Or:

class Pickup(Vehicle):

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.cab_style = input("Please enter the cab style: ")
    self.bed_length = float(input("Please enter the bed length: "))

def get_cab_style(self):
    return self.cab_style

def get_bed_length(self):
    return self.bed_length
```

Would it have anything to do with how the functions are being called?

```
new_vehicle = Vehicle()
new_vehicle.get_make()
new_vehicle.get_model()
new_vehicle.get_color()
new_vehicle.get_fuel_type()
new_vehicle.get_options()

new_vehicle_car = Cars()
new_vehicle_car.get_engine_size()
new_vehicle_car.get_num_doors()

new_vehicle_pickup = Pickup()
new_vehicle_pickup.get_cab_style()
new_vehicle_pickup.get_bed_length()
```

Any help will be appreciated. Here is my entire program so far, instead of separate snippets:

```
class Vehicle:

    def __init__(self):
        self.vehicle_type_request = int(input("Hello! Press 1 to add a Car to your garage or 2 to add a Pickup: "))
        self.make = input("Please enter the make of your vehicle: ")
        self.model = input("Please enter the model of your vehicle: ")
        self.color = input("Please enter the color of your vehicle: ")
        self.fuel_type = input("Please enter the fuel type: ")
        self.options = []

    def welcome_message(self):
        if self.vehicle_type_request == 1:
            self.vehicle_type_request = Cars()
        else:
            self.vehicle_type_request = Pickup()
        return self.vehicle_type_request

    def get_make(self):
        return self.make

    def get_model(self):
        return self.model

    def get_color(self):
        return self.color

    def get_fuel_type(self):
        return self.fuel_type

    def get_options(self):
        self.options = input("Please choose any applicable vehicle options: ")


class Cars(Vehicle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.engine_size = float(input("Please enter the engine size: "))
        self.num_doors = int(input("How many doors does your vehicle have? "))

    def get_engine_size(self):
        return self.engine_size

    def get_num_doors(self):
        return self.num_doors


class Pickup(Vehicle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.cab_style = input("Please enter the cab style: ")
        self.bed_length = float(input("Please enter the bed length: "))

    def get_cab_style(self):
        return self.cab_style

    def get_bed_length(self):
        return self.bed_length


new_vehicle = Vehicle()
new_vehicle.get_make()
new_vehicle.get_model()
new_vehicle.get_color()
new_vehicle.get_fuel_type()
new_vehicle.get_options()

new_vehicle_car = Cars()
new_vehicle_car.get_engine_size()
new_vehicle_car.get_num_doors()

new_vehicle_pickup = Pickup()
new_vehicle_pickup.get_cab_style()
new_vehicle_pickup.get_bed_length()
```

Comment: have a serious look at `welcome_message`, the parent class instance has members that are instances of child classes, don't do `input()` in the constructor, it does not allow you to use different sources like files

Comment: if you say the flow of the program is not what you want, also tell what you expect the program should do.

Answer (score 0):

I sugguest OP follow a better tutorial to learn Python/Programming. I don't know where to begin to teach you the foundations of programming, but I can list a few observations of where you got it wrong:

1. In the code, the `.get_**()` functions have absolutely no effect. You can delete the lines and observe that the program behaves exactly the same.
2. The flow didn't go *backwards*, the program did exactly what you told it to do. In `new_vehicle = Vehicle()`, `new_vehicle_car = Cars()` and `new_vehicle_pickup = Pickup()`, each time it asks you for all the inputs(in total 3 times). You can remove some lines to see the effect.

Learning to program is a lot of fun, I only mean to provide some help here. I suggest OP understand more basics before trying to mess with Class.